# 2 subroutines in marie

Tags: string, user-input, subroutine, marie

I need a Marie file with 2 different subroutines operating. The first is printing a string that I enter into the code, and the second is printing a string that the user inputs 1 character at a time.

I've got them both working separately, but when I try to combine them into one file it will only print my string and not ask for the user input like I want it to do afterwards.

The way I've been combining them is putting the user input code directly after the first string code, removing the extra "Print, HEX 0" definition as Marie won't run with them both.

My string code:

```
Load StringAddr1  
Store StringToPrint  
Jns Print  
Halt

Print, HEX 0
Load StringToPrint
Store Position
StartLoop, LoadI Position   
Skipcond 800
JumpI Print
Output          
Load Position
Add One 
Store Position
Jump StartLoop

Position, HEX 0 
StringToPrint, HEX 0
One, HEX 1

StringAddr1, Jns XXX    
           XXX, HEX X   
                HEX X
                HEX X
                HEX X
                HEX X
                HEX X
                HEX X
                HEX X
                HEX X
                HEX X
                HEX X
                HEX X
                HEX X
                HEX X
                HEX X
```

My user input code:

```
Load StringAddr2 
Store InputAddr 
Jns InputString 
Halt

InputAddr, HEX 0
InputString, HEX 0
Input
Store Print_Arg
JnS   Print
Halt

Print_Arg, DEC 0
Print, HEX 0
Load Print_Arg
Output
Skipcond 800
Halt

StringAddr2, JnS UserInput
UserInput,  HEX 0
```

Comment: Your user Input also does have an output? Is this purposely done?